# Google Sheets: Find match, check for text in adjacent cell to matched cell

Tags: regex, filter, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting, textjoin

[Example data here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FN72c_4yk6av-KbkHi6uzNv1tWFtyxAlGCjm7qm5bDM/edit?usp=sharing)

I'd like to use conditional formatting to highlight cells where, if the cell's number is found in another sheet, and there is text in an adjacent cell, it is highlighted.

So, given Sheet2:

[image]

When a B-column cell in Sheet1 matches an A-column cell in Sheet2, it checks if there is text in the adjacent E-column cell (in Sheet2), and highlights if there is text.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B2&"", "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, 
 FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"), INDIRECT("Sheet2!E2:E")<>""))&"$")
```

[image]